# Insert the value from one table into another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following SQL. I am trying to insert the `ClientName` from `Clients` into the `pName` column in `CommisionPickups`. I need to make sure that all the values are unique.

```
insert into CommisionPickups (pName) 
   (select ClientName 
    from Clients  
    where ClientName <> CommisionPickups.pName)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `<>` to check uniqueness. To ensure that all names are unique, you need to make sure that you select unique names from `CommisionPickups`, and that the names you insert do not already exist in `Clients`. Use `NOT EXISTS` for `CommisionPickups`, and `DISTINCT` for `Clients`, like this:

```
insert into CommisionPickups (pName) 
(select DISTINCT c.ClientName from Clients c
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CommisionPickups cp
                  WHERE c.ClientName = cp.pName)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

i am not able to get your question but i understand partly may be you asking for this

if you want to insert distant value in pname than make pname as unique it will work automatically 
and select

```
select  DISTINCT ClientName from Clients
```

take a look this one u can get

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp

Comment: I need to copy all the date from the ClientName field from the Clients table which isn't already in the pName field on the CommisionPickups table. The way you suggested will only select Unique or Distinct values from the Clients table.

Answer (score 1):

here is a way to achieve it. I am working in SQL Server but i hope it will work for any Database Engine

```
    INSERT  INTO CommisionPickups ( pName )
    SELECT DISTINCT
            ClientName
    FROM    Client
    WHERE   ClientName NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                        pName
                                FROM    CommisionPickups )
```